# Opening a file from TFS gives Error TF10187

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, tfs

I am connected to a project in TFS, After making my changes I checked in. I can now see the folders and files on the server in source control. However, all of my new files and changes to certain files are not available in my solution.

Error Message:
Error

TF10187:Could not open document
(Path)

The system cannot find the file specified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Source Control Explorer, select your project and use the Get Latest Version command (a little icon with an arrow pointing at a clock). This will download all files missing on your local PC from TFS.

Comment: Tried it but doesn't help.

Comment: Try deleting the file from the project and re-adding it again using Add existing... In some cases this helps. I have found no reasonable explanation of this problem other than it often happens with .sql files, in which case SQL Server is to blame.

Comment: Still can see the files. And they are .xaml and .cs files not .sql  files.

Comment: So you mean you can't delete them from the solution?

Comment: Oh no. Misspelled can't as can. LOL!

Comment: It happens :-) . So in your solutions the files are not present and you are unable to add them via Add existing? Is there an error?

Comment: They are there. But adding them checks out the files and undo changes deletes them.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44990/discussion-between-mzetko-and-user2951819)

Comment: Okay. I am there on chat